# Send fcm message to specific topic via retrofit android (kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit

Im trying to send message for specific topic in fcm via retrofit i follow the instructions in fcm but i keep getting 404 code for my http request thats my code:

Constants file:

```
class Constans {

companion object{
    const val BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com"
    const val CONTENT_TYPE  ="application/json"
    const val SERVER_KEY ="myKey"
}
```

}

NotificationApi:

```
interface NotificationApi {

@Headers("Authorization: key=$SERVER_KEY", "Content-Type:${CONTENT_TYPE}")
@POST("fcm/send")
suspend fun postNotification(
    @Body message: Message
): Response<ResponseBody>
```

}

RetrofitInstance:

```
class RetrofitInstance {

companion object{
    private val retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val api by lazy {
        retrofit.create(NotificationApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

}

Message class:

```
data class Message(
    var to:String,
    var data:Notification,
)
```

Notification class:

```
data class Notification (
    val body:String="",
    val title:String=""
)
```

send notification function:

```
    private fun sendNotification(body:String,title:String)= CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        //orders is the topic name
        val message = Message("orders",Notification(body,title))
        val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(message)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Log.e("msg1", response.message())
        } else {
            //here i get 404
            Log.e("msg", response.code().toString())
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Error", e.message.toString())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to modify your code like this

```
    interface NotificationApi {

    @Headers("Authorization: key=$SERVER_KEY", "Content-Type:$CONTENT_TYPE")
    @POST("fcm/send")
    suspend fun postNotification(
      @Body message: Message
    ): Response<ResponseBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but What happen if you change the `Notification Api - @Headers` to

```
interface NotificationApi {

@Headers("Authorization: Bearer $SERVER_KEY", "Content-Type:${CONTENT_TYPE}")
@POST("fcm/send")
suspend fun postNotification(
    @Body message: Message
): Response<ResponseBody>
```

Comment: No thing happened same error , i try to make same steps i did for another application and link it to the same firebase project and it works perfectly that's the most weird error i have faced in my life.